# How to get user permissions of a file with Excel 2003 VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, file-permissions

I am very new to [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and I was tasked to make a list of the files in a given folder as well as the users with permissions for every file.

- I was able to get the filenames in the folder,
- but I don't know how to get the list of users with permissions.

I am using excel 2003.

I found this code which adds 'everyone' to the permissions of a folder:

> 'Adds everyone in the permissions Function SetPermissions()
>       Dim strHomeFolder, strHome, strUser
>       Dim intRunError, objShell, objFSO
>
> ```
> strHomeFolder = "C:\Test"
>
> Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
> Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
> If objFSO.FolderExists(strHomeFolder) Then
>     intRunError = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| cacls " _
>     & strHomeFolder & " /e /c /g everyone:F ", 2, True)
>
>     If intRunError <> 0 Then
>         Wscript.Echo "Error assigning permissions for user " _
>         & strUser & " to home folder " & strHomeFolder
>     End If
> End If End Function
> ```

However, i don't know how to modify the code to return the current permissions granted by the specified folder. I would also like to do this for a specified file. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Google *vbscript* (executable as vba in Excel), *file permissions*, *acl*. That should get you started

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the owner of a file, this function might help you:

```
Function GetFileOwner(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As String
Dim secUtil As Object
Dim secDesc As Object
Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
GetFileOwner = secDesc.owner
End Function
```

Comment: Checking at immediate window, I've obtained this piece of answer:<br>`?GetFileOwner("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\","log.docx")`<br> `LOC\Octopus`

Comment: Thank you Octopus for the code. Unfortunately, i need the permissions of the file, not the owner. But I appreciate your help. Thanks again!